# Intellij navigate through multiple maven projects

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

So I have a file structure that looks like this:

```
.git
.project
.classpath
app1
    pom.xml
    .classpath
    .project
    src
app2
    pom.xml
    .classpath
    .project
    src
app3
    pom.xml
    .classpath
    .project
    src
TheAppIWorkOn
    pom.xml
    .classpath
    .project
    src
```

TheAppIWorkOn uses jars from app1, 2, and 3 which are maven dependencies so when I need to edit something in app1, 2, or 3 it's a painful process. If I use the "jump to declaration" functionality it just shows me the locked jar. Is it possible to set it up so that when I "Jump to declaration" it take me to the actual code that I can make edits on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would have a [maven reactor build](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) it would have made all the module setup for you. Now you only have dependencies to jar files and IntelliJ cannot know that you have the modules to depend on. But you can help IntelliJ by pointing out the module dependencies and after that you will be able to navigate between all the classes in the project.

The best way would be to create a `pom.xml` in the root directory of the project. This pom would keep together the different modules and also define the build order. When you want to open the project for the first time you just point IntelliJ to this pom file and all the dependencies would be resolved and setup so the navigation between classes in the different modules is a breeze.

Sample pom file for the root directory:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>Q16589702</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>app1</module>
        <module>app2</module>
        <module>app3</module>
        <module>TheAppIWorkOn</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

If you cannot do this for some reason then you'll have to inform IntelliJ about the module dependencies. You do this by opening up the `Project Structure`.

[image]

Then select the module `TheAppIWorkOn` and press the plus sign in the bottom and choose `Module Dependency...`.

[image]

And there you can select all modules that you want to have as dependency.

[image]

Press <kbd>Ok</kbd> and then <kbd>Ok</kbd> again.

[image]

Now you will be able to navigate between the different classes in the project.

If `app1`, `app2` and `app3` also have dependencies between each other then you will have to do the same for them.

But the simplest way is definitely to have a pom file in the root project directory with all inter module dependencies there.