# 'Go to definition' in a multi-module maven project with module dependencies in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have a parent module with two child modules (`module1` and `module2`)

`module2` has a maven dependency to `module1`

In `module2` I reference a class that's in `module1`

When I try to jump to the definition of this class, IntelliJ opens the .class file in my maven repository. I expect it to jump to the java class in `module1`. How can I get IntelliJ to jump this class file?

I'm running IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 14.0.1

`parent` pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>module2</module>
        <module>module1</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

`module1` pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>test</artifactId>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
</project>
```

`module2` pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>test</artifactId>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>module2</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test</groupId>
            <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Please, show us your pom files, all three

Comment: I've added the pom files to the question

Comment: Ok, your poms seem correct, so Idea should be able to work with that and give you direct navigation between classes in modules. How did you open the project? It's a good idea to start idea with all projects closed, configure maven, then use file/open to import the master pom. Then, go to a class in module 2 that references a class in module 1, and try to navigate (ctrl-click) on the class name.

Comment: And, do you have your java in the standard maven directory structure: `src/main/java/...`?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the issue again, but I can't anymore. I've been fiddling around with the maven settings in IntelliJ last week, and I've apparently fixed the problem. I can now CTRL+Click normally. Thanks for all your help Engineer Dollery :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellij navigate through multiple maven projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589702/intellij-navigate-through-multiple-maven-projects)

Answer (score 0):

This other answer [over here at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589702/intellij-navigate-through-multiple-maven-projects) helped me.  You essentially have to add module dependencies if they're not already in place.

Answer (score -1):

You have two options:

Way #1:

Build `module1` with sources. This way ensures that you will have always consistent source code to used java classes.

To enable build with sources add this to maven plugins:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Way #2:

Add your `module1` to `module2` via `Project structure` > `Modules` > `Dependencies` > `+` > `3. Module dependency`

Well, it wont be as consistent as way #1 but its much faster to setup, if you are using maven builds. If you are using intellij idea build you can mark this dependency as `export` to include it in your `module1` output dir.

Comment: Neither of these is necessary, or even necessarily a good idea. If your maven dependencies are right and you've imported the project from the master pom, then navigation should 'just' work.

Comment: I agree with Engineer Dollery. I've tried way #2 before, and as soon as you re-import your maven project you have to setup the dependencies again. Way #1 would just bring me to the sources in my maven repository, not the sources in my project.